# How to test for the success or failure of a C++ STL function (in Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In the Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0 STL implementation
how, as a user of one of the STL classes do you determine
if the function has failed?

For example, `vector::insert` has these prototypes:

```
void insert(iterator it, size_type n, const T& x);
void insert(iterator it, const_iterator first, const_iterator last);
```

But there is no failure return value and there is no mention
in the documentation of an exception thrown to indicate
a failure.

Does anyone know how to test for a failure in this or
another STL class in MSVC++ 6.0 ? Thanks!

Comment: Visual C++ 6, are you serious? Burn it. Burn it with fire!

Comment: The exception contingencies are mentioned in the standard; they would probably not find their (explicit) way in most STL documentations.

Comment: Nuke it from orbit. It's the only way to be sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inserting into a vector won't fail unless the container is unable to allocate memory or your copy constructor throws an exception. In both cases, you detect the failure by catching the exception.